# Is there a saving throw if you cast Scrying and target a location you've seen?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw, targeting

The [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell description states:

> You can see and hear a particular creature you choose that is on the same plane of existence as you. The target must make a Wisdom saving throw [...]

However, later in the spell, it has a clause that states:

> Instead of targeting a creature, you can choose a location you have seen before as the target of this spell. When you do, the sensor appears at that location and doesn't move.

Does this bypass the saving throw then?

Comment: I think I’m missing something. Are you really asking if a location has to make a saving throw, or something else?

Comment: I suspect the question is, if you know that someone is in a room and you cast *Scrying* targeting the room instead of the person, does it allow you to scry on them with no save? But if so, I agree it should be asked more clearly.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell states:

> You can see and hear a particular creature you choose that is on the same plane of existence as you. The target must make a Wisdom saving throw, which is modified by how well you know the target and the sort of physical connection you have to it. If a target knows you're casting this spell, it can fail the saving throw voluntarily if it wants to be observed.
>
> [...]
>
> Instead of targeting a creature, you can choose a location you have seen before as the target of this spell. When you do, the sensor appears at that location and doesn't move.

First off, it wouldn't really make sense for a *location* to make a saving throw, and that's rather strong evidence that one isn't made, but we can look closer as well if that isn't enough.

Notably, the targeting-a-location clause happens at the very end of the spell description, well after the other clauses. While this doesn't *explicitly* mean the previous parts don't apply to it, we can logically conclude that they do not or the location effects would have been listed sooner. Furthermore, the location-targeting bit simply says the sensor appears and doesn't move without restating any of the saving throw requirements.

From these I would conclude that the saving throw simply does not happen when targeting a location.

Comment: I really feel like you should just lead with “locations don’t make saving throws”.

Comment: Based on Ryan’s comment on the question, OP may be asking if a creature in the location you’re scrying on saves against the spell if you choose to scry on a location.